# django autofill manytomany field in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Good day, not so long ago, working with Django.
Encountered the following problem.

There are two models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    productID       = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    brandID         = models.ForeignKey(Brand, verbose_name=u'Бренд')
    categoryID      = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=u'Категория')
    productPhotos   = models.ManyToManyField("ProductPhoto", verbose_name = "Фотографии товара", related_name="photos", blank=True)

class ProductPhoto(models.Model):
    productPhotoID      = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    productID           = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    imageFile           = models.FileField(u'Путь к изображение', upload_to=makeUploadPath)
    dateModified        = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

For admin use the following TabularInline

```
class ProductPhotoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductPhoto
    verbose_name = u"Фото"
    verbose_name_plural = u"Фотографии"

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title')
    search_fields = ...
    fieldsets = ...
    )
    inlines = [ ProductPhotoInline, ]
```

The problem when you add a product in the table ProdcutPhoto productId field is filled, and the field in the table Products productPhotos is empty. How best to do to fill both fields.

Comment: Just curios. Why do you want to edit this inline? You defined productPhotos on your Product class. In this case the admin interface for Product should give you a possibility to choose an existing ProductPhoto oder add a new one if you like to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the productPhotos ManyToMany field, it's redundant. If each photo is only attached to one product, then the productID ForeignKey is all you need.

To access the photos from a product instance, you can use `productphoto_set`, e.g.

```
product = Product.objects.get(pk=1)
photos = product.productphoto_set.all()
```